# Goeritz matrix and link coloring

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

For a link $L$ and a prime $p$, $L$ has a $p$-coloring iff $p$ divides the $\operatorname{gcd}$ of the invariant factors of the Goeritz matrix of $L$.

Do you know the elementary proof of this facts?

Comment: Please use TeX. Besides, more details and definitions would help.

Answer (score 3):

A very nice treatment of this is given in Chapter 9 of Lickorish's book, "An introduction to knot theory". He explains that the Goeritz matrix is a presentation matrix for the first homology of the double branched cover of the knot. It is relatively straightforward to prove that there is a $p$-coloring iff there is a dihedral representation of the knot group iff $p$ divides the order of that first homology. The latter equivalence uses the fact that the covering transformation acts by $-1$ on the first homology of the double branched cover.

Comment: Moreover, isn't it true that the dimension of the $\mathbb{F}_p$-vector space of p-colorings of a knot is equal to the dimension of  $\mathbb{F}_p \otimes M$, where $M$ denotes the first homology of the double branched covering?

Comment: Dear Prof. Danny Ruberman, 

thank you very much for your reply.